# SFMC Related Data Extension filtering when a relationship doesn't exist

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm trying to filter a DE using fields from a related DE, but specifically, I want to only include records that don't exist in the related DE.

eg.

I want to filter a DE of all my customers (`de_customers`) for those who have not ordered anything from us. That order information would be stored in a separate DE `de_orders` and related to each other by a `customer_id`.

A customer who hasn't ordered anything from us would not have any records in the `de_orders` data extension.

How would I filter for those who don't have any orders then?

I tried to filter by `order_id` is empty but that doesn't seem to work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT customer_id FROM de_customers
WHERE customer_id NOT IN (SELECT customer_id FROM de_orders)
```

It will pull all customers who exist in the customers DE but don’t exist in the orders DE.

Alternatively, you could also use a left join to achieve the same result:

```
SELECT c.customer_id 
FROM de_customers c LEFT JOIN de_orders d
ON c.customer_id = d.customer_id
WHERE d.customer_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, any chance this can be done using the drag and drop UI? While I can write SQL I would like a bit more autonomy for my team who aren't as technical?